# Selenium IDE - how to target delete links in Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-ide

What's a good way to target delete links in rails applications?

For example this link

```
<a href="/auto_policies/autos/10693.mobile" class="remove-auto"
 data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-icon="delete" data-method="delete" 
 data-remote="true"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, target the ID (or add one and target it).
If this is not possible, for example you don't have access to check the rails code then use the following method:

Target the element with the class `.remove-auto` to scope it down to just selecting "remove auto" links.
Then make sure it is a delete link with `[data-method=delete]`.

Thus you end up targeting the delete link with

```
a.remove-auto[data-method=delete]
```